# Bash - create a nonexistent directory

Tags: bash

I have catalogs

```
site_2021-11-09_0
site_2021-11-09_1
site_2021-11-09_2
site_2021-11-09_3
site_2021-11-09_4
site_2021-11-09_5
site_2021-11-09_6
```

I need to add next directory that does not exist, which is `site_2021-11-09_7`. I need to write a script on loops. How can this be done?

I currently have

```sh
#!/bin/bash

date="$(date +%F)"
site="site"

i="0"

while [ ! -d ${site}_${date}_$i ]
do
    echo ${site}_${date}_$i
    mkdir ${site}_${date}_$i
    i=$(( $i + 1))
done
```

but it doesn't work. If no directories exist, it works forever. If there is directory `site_2021-11-09_0`, it doesn't work at all. How to understand it logically?

Comment: You coded  _As long as the directory does not exist, create the directory_. This is not what you want. you want _As long as the directory exist, move to the next, if it does not create it_. There are about an infinite way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ways to achieve what you want:

```
i=0; while [ -d "${site}_${date}_$i" ]; do ((i++)); done; mkdir -v "${site}_${date}_$i"
i=0; while ! mkdir "${site}_${date}_$i"; do ((i++)); done
i=0; for d in "${site}_${date}_"*; do ((i=i>${d##*_}:i?${d##*_})); done; mkdir -v "${site}_${date}_$((i+1))"
```

when your directories are sortable, that is only when the index counter has a fixed amount of digits, (e.g. `${site}_${date}_001`, `${site}_${date}_002` , ... , `${site}_${date}_078`), you can make use of the lexicographical ordering of `globs`

```
dirlist=( "${site}_${date}"_* )
mkdir -v "${site}_${date}_$(printf "%.3d" "$((10#${dirlist[-1]##*_}+1))")"
```

Comment: Wow. You have given so many possibilities. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

Presently your code is doing

```
while (directory does not exist)
    do stuff
```

but your first directory `site_2021-11-09_0` does indeed exist. So the condition inside the while is never satisfied and so the program doesn't run. You can make a slight modification to your code by changing the logic to keep running as long as the directory exists and then make a new directory with the next index when the loop is broken

```sh
#! /bin/sh

date="$(date +%F)"
site="site"

i="0"

while [ -d ${site}_${date}_$i ]
do
    echo ${site}_${date}_$i
    i=$(( $i + 1))
done
mkdir ${site}_${date}_$i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

prefix=${1:?no site given}_$(date +%F)_

while [[ -d "$prefix$((i++))" ]]; do :; done

mkdir "$prefix$((i-1))"
```

Call like `./mk-site-dir sitename`.

You can hardcode `sitename` if you want.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, `mkdir` will fail if the name already exists. This script could probably be improved with `if ! mkdir "$prefix$((i-1))"; then echo "failed to create directory $prefix$((i-1))" >&2; exit 1; fi`, or the less portable `mkdir -v`, which will print why it failed (or that it was successful).

Answer (score 0):

As @kvantour says, you currently make a directory so long as it doesn't exist, and then increment `i`.  Thus in any empty directory it will run indefinitely; whereas if there is a matching dir after 0 your code will make all the directories *before* it and then stop.  What you want is probably:

```sh
while [ -d ${site}_${date}_$i ]
do
    i=$(( $i + 1))
done

mkdir ${site}_${date}_$i
```

I.e. get the first directory which *doesn't* exist, and then make it.